# Heroku Rails 4 Assets being precompiled but failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

In my `index.html.erb` in the Public folder, I hold the landing page to my website. I don't yet have a true website, so there only needs to be a landing page.

This landing page has many images. The images are all stored in `app/assets/images`. When I run `git push heroku`, my assets get pre-compiled, and from that point on all of my images are in the `public/assets` folder following a `imagename-hash.png` format.

In my `index.html.erb`, the one I use as the landing page, I attempt to access these images through `<img class="android-device" src=<%= asset_path("nexus_large.png")%> >` and I expect `asset_path` to return to me `nexus_large-hash.png`. For some reason, it does not. When I go to the webpage, none of my images are loaded up. I get 404 errors when trying to retrieve the assets.

I have `rails-12factor` as a gem in my Gemfile. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Through `heroku run bash` I confirmed that the assets were precompiled and placed into `public/assets`. Through `helper.asset_path("nexus_large.png")` in the Rails console, I confirmed that it should return `/assets/nexus_large-hash.png`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Upon further inspection, if I were to go to `mywebsite.com/assets/nexus_large-hash.png` I would see the appropriate image. So 100% precompilation is successful. It's linking to the images that is failing.

Comment: When I replace the `/assets/nexus_large.png` with its `/assets/nexus_large-hash.png` counterpart, one indeed sees the image. That being said, one hopes they don't have to rely on hard-coding all of the hashes...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This comes down to wanting to over-optimize and not do things the simple way.

I didn't want to create another controller to house an empty action that would render my landing page. I felt that there was a better way. So, what I did was I used Rails mechanism to render the Public index.html when it is present and you're at the root. In a sense, it is a landing page. The problem is it doesn't react to Ruby. Even if you change it to index.html.erb, it simply won't respond to the changes you requested.

So, the solution is quite simply to use a controller action and have `root to: 'controller#action'` in your `routes.rb`. Then, all the helpers work perfectly.